# What is the difference between Context.sendBroadcastAsUser and Context.startActivity?

Tags: android

What does UserHandle, included in the arguments for sendBroadcastAsUser, add and how does it change how the system handles the intent?

Comment: im not sure what you mean, one sends a broadcast and the other starts an activity. They are completely different in nature

Comment: Can you narrow down your question? Such as, did you read the documentation for it, did you Google or stackoverflow about it? If so, what did/didn't you understand?

Answer (score 1):

> SendBroadcastAsUser(Intent intent, UserHandle user, string
>   receiverPermission);

1. Version of sendBroadcast(Intent, String) that allows you to specify the user the broadcast will be sent to.
2. This is not available to applications that are not pre-installed on the system image. Using it requires holding the INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS permission.sendBroadcast(Intent, String)
   Version Information
3. Supported after Android v4.2

> Context.startActivity

Used to start a different activity.